# How to clone a local repository to Github (with permission denied error)

Tags: git, github, repository, clone

I have a file of code stored locally that was sent to me by someone I hired to write code. The folder already has a .git folder inside of it. I want to clone the contents of the folder to my own github repository. When I run git clone I get the following error:

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How do I get around this? I have all the code on my desktop already so is there a way to get around this and create a repository from the folder's contents?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to push and not clone. Once you create a new repository on GitHub, you can run this command from the local repository with the existing .git file to create a link from the local repo to the upstream repo:
`git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/yourreponame`
Then run this command to push the contents of your local repo to your upstream repo:
`git push origin main` (where "main" is the name of the branch you want to push up; if you're not sure of the name of the branch, just run `git branch` and use the name with an asterisk next to it.)

If you get an error from the first command that "origin" already exists, this just means that there's already a link called "origin" between your local repo and another upstream repo. In that case, just replace the word "origin" with a different name in both commands, like "upstream".

Comment: Sweet I did get the origin error so thanks for the help. But now I am getting this error: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @Neo - can you confirm that you own the repo you're trying to push to?